# Arrays transformation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here I have two arrays and I need to transform first array to be in format like second array...

First array is driving directions from google map so:`response.routes[0].overview_path` produce something like:

```
An array of LatLngs representing the entire course of this route. The path is simplified in order to make it suitable in contexts where a small number of vertices is required (such as Static Maps API URLs).
```

CODE

```
[
  new google.maps.LatLng(12.34, 56.789),
  new google.maps.LatLng(87.65, 123.45)
]
```

so I have this:

```
[
  [56.789, 12.34],
  [123.45, 87.65]
]
```

and I need to trasform this array with javascript in this format:

```
[
  [
    {
      X: 12.34
      Y: 56.789
    },
    {
      X: 87.65,
      Y: 123.45
    }
  ]
]
```

So how I can do this?
Is there any way?
How to transform first array to in format like second with X and Y?

**UPDATE:**
I do this:

```
tacke = response.routes[0].overview_path;
 rezultat = [tacke.map(function(w) { return {X:w[1], Y:w[0]}; })];
```

and now `console.log(rezultat);` produce this code:

```
console.log(rezultat);
[Array[220]]
0: Array[220]
[0 … 99]
0: Object
X: undefined
Y: undefined
__proto__: Object
1: Object
X: undefined
Y: undefined
__proto__: Object
2: Object
X: undefined
Y: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Why here is X and Y undefinded...

DEMO:http://jsbin.com/uTATePe/41 CODE:http://jsbin.com/uTATePe/41/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var olddata = [
  [56.789, 12.34],
  [123.45, 87.65]
]
var newdata = [olddata.map(function(w) { return {X:w[1], Y:w[0]}; })];
```

Comment: yes but there must be some "for" function, becouse this is array with approximately 200 elements...

Comment: @drCode, you probably don't know how [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works: the function passed as argument is called for every item of the array, so it's an implicit "for", let's say.

Comment: Just wrap the assignment with extra brackets: `var newdata = [[olddata.map(function(w) { return {X:w[1], Y:w[0]}; })]];`

Comment: Is there any way to X and Y get the good values, not undefined

Comment: if your issue is that `X` or `Y` may be undefined, you can filter: `[olddata.map(function(w) { return {X:w[1], Y:w[0]}; }).filter(function(w) { return typeof w.X !== "undefined" && typeof w.Y !== "undefined"})];`, although it's not obvious to me why you would have undefined values in the first place (is google maps sending you bad data?)

Comment: no as you can see on my example: http://jsbin.com/uTATePe/41, console.log(tacke) return good values

Comment: @drCode I don't see the line `console.log(tacke)`.  I do see `  console.log(JSON.stringify(offsetted_polygon));`

Comment: no, you need to type console.log when pick a city in the list menu

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must use a `for` loop, this will create the data structure you want. I still recommend [Nirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583175/nirk)'s solution.

```
var data = [
  [56.789, 12.34],
  [123.45, 87.65]
];

var result = [[]];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    result[0].push({"X": data[i][0], "Y": data[i][1]});   
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/An9nz/2/)**

Comment: Use case for above: `Array.prototype.map` is not supported in IE8.

Comment: @Robusto you can implement it directly if it is not available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility